# XML conversion using XSLT, need to fetch max expirationdate from multiple complex types

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have below node structure and I need to fetch maximum `<FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>` among all `<partSupplierFTA>` in XSLT. Can somebody please help me on this?

```
<modelMasterHeader>
   <sender>sender3889</sender>
   <receiver>receiver3890</receiver>
   <messageType>messageType3891</messageType>
   <batchID>97</batchID>
   <modelMaster>
      <ACTION>M</ACTION>
      <PARTNUMBER>PARTNUMBER3893</PARTNUMBER>
      <productCountry>
         <COUNTRYCODE>COUNTRYCODE3894</COUNTRYCODE>
         <COUNTRYGROUP>COUNTRYGROUP3895</COUNTRYGROUP>
         <LOCALPARTDESCRIPTION>LOCALPARTDESCRIPTION3896</LOCALPARTDESCRIPTION>
         <COUNTRYOFORIGIN>COUNTRYOFORIGIN3897</COUNTRYOFORIGIN>
         <HS>-0</HS>
         <HSDESCRIPTION>HSDESCRIPTION3898</HSDESCRIPTION>
         <SOURCESYSTEM>SOURCESYSTEM3899</SOURCESYSTEM>
         <ECCNUM>ECCNUM3900</ECCNUM>
         <USEGENLIC>USEGENLIC3901</USEGENLIC>
         <EXPORTHARMONIZEDTARIFFNUMBER>-0</EXPORTHARMONIZEDTARIFFNUMBER>
         <PARTUNIT>PARTUNIT3902</PARTUNIT>
      </productCountry>
      <Supplier>
         <PARTSUPPCOUNTRYOFORIGIN></PARTSUPPCOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
         <PRIMARYFLAG>Y</PRIMARYFLAG>
         <CTRY_OF_IMPORT>US</CTRY_OF_IMPORT>
         <SEQ_NO>23</SEQ_NO>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>1</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>11/30/2012</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>US</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>H</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8414593000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>2</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>12/31/2013</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>CN</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>V</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8414593000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>1</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>12/31/2012</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>AU</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>V</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8302103000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
        </Supplier>
        <Supplier>
         <PARTSUPPCOUNTRYOFORIGIN></PARTSUPPCOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
         <PRIMARYFLAG>Y</PRIMARYFLAG>
         <CTRY_OF_IMPORT>US</CTRY_OF_IMPORT>
         <SEQ_NO>23</SEQ_NO>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>1</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>11/30/2012</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>US</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>H</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8414593000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>2</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>12/31/2013</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>CN</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>V</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8414593000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
         <SupplierFTA>
            <FTASITEID>GLOBAL</FTASITEID>
            <FTASEQNO2>1</FTASEQNO2>
            <FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>12/31/2012</FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE>
            <FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>AU</FTACOUNTRYOFORIGIN>
            <FTASTATUS>V</FTASTATUS>
            <FTAHTSNUMBER>8302103000</FTAHTSNUMBER>
         </SupplierFTA>
        </Supplier>
     </ModelMaster>
   </ModelMasterHeader>
```

Comment: Are you required to use XSLT1 or is XSLT2 an option?

Answer (score 1):

This will find the latest date, using XSLT2.  If you need to find the containing `<SupplierFTA>` node, this should give you a starting point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:variable name="a" select="//FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE/text()"/>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:value-of select="max(for $x in $a return xs:date(replace($x,'^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)$','$3-$1-$2')))"/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Jim, Thanks for the reply but I am using XSLT1.0. will this work in 1.0 also ?

Comment: Jim, I have updated my actual payload above, here I need to pick up maximum of ftacertexpirationdate among all <supplierfta> for each <supplier>. So, please give me how to loop it for each supplier (I also have other mappings in each supplier and supplierfta where I am using for-each and if conidtions)

Comment: Well, this solution is XSLT2-only.  I haven't worked enough with XSLT1 to help.  I'm sure it's possible, but a LOT more work.

Answer (score 0):

While it is rather inefficient, you could use an `xsl:for-each` and sort the values by Year, Month, and Day and select the first item:

```
<xsl:for-each select="
        /modelMasterHeader/modelMaster/Supplier/SupplierFTA/FTACERTEXPIRATIONDATE
        ">
    <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number" 
        select="substring-after(substring-after(., '/'), '/')"/>
    <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number" 
        select="substring-before(substring-after(., '/'), '/')"/>
    <xsl:sort order="descending" data-type="number" 
        select="substring-before(.,'/')"/>
    <xsl:if test="position()=1">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Mads, Thanks for your reply. I have updated my xml payload can you please have a look on it and and tell me how to set this code in the loop. I am new to this xslt so, please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Mads we have used your solution. Its working. Will reach you in case of any doubts.

Comment: Updated the XPath in the for-each to match the updated XML document, which will be a bit more efficient than using `//`.